# Process hdiutil output with PlistBuddy

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, plist, plistbuddy

I'm trying to parse the output from `hdiutil` using `PlistBuddy` on the Mac terminal (without using a temporary file) and I'm running into some issues. I've tried the following:

### Command 1

`hdiutil info -plist | PlistBuddy -c "Print"`

#### Output:

Prints the help for PlistBuddy

---

### Command 2

`PlistBuddy -c "Print" $(hdiutil info -plist)`

#### Output:

`File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: <?xml
Invalid Arguments`

---

I'm not great at bash but I think it might be an issue with PlistBuddy not accepting STDIN but only `.plist` files as input. Is there something that I'm missing or do I have to create a temporary file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var=$(hdiutil info -plist)

PlistBuddy -c "Print" /dev/stdin <<< "$var"